# adding new numeration when clicked move up or move down

Tags: jquery

How change this solution http://jsfiddle.net/RrbzM/4/ and add each line numbering even if clicked move down or move up?

```
$(function () {
    function buttonInit() {
        $('.button a').show().filter(':first,:last').hide();
    }
    $('.button a').live('click', function (event) {
        var $parent = $(this).closest('.box');
        ($(event.target).hasClass('up')) ? $parent.insertBefore($parent.prev()) : $parent.insertAfter($parent.next());
        buttonInit();
        return false;
    });
    buttonInit();
});
```

Comment: So after clicking, the list will look unchanged? Won't that be confusing?

Comment: div have to move how adding new number e. g. 
1- div2
2- div1
3- div4

Comment: Div at the top always is to get No1. next No2 ...